C code for sorting 4 byte integers in a file using MPI gives memory ranges overlap error
Below, I have a C code that is supposed to take in a file with various 4-byte integers and sort them in ascending order using MPI functions:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define MAX 999
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000
#define BLOCK_SIZE (BUFFER_SIZE / sizeof(int))

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int rank, size;
    int *buffer, *local_counts, *local_data;
    int count[MAX + 1] = {0};
    char file_name[256];
    MPI_Offset file_size, local_size, offset;
    MPI_File file;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (rank == 0) {
        printf("Enter a file name: ");
        scanf("%s", file_name);

        MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_SELF, file_name, MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &file);

        MPI_File_get_size(file, &file_size);
        buffer = (int *)malloc(file_size);
        MPI_File_read(file, buffer, file_size / sizeof(int), MPI_INT, &status);
        MPI_File_close(&file);

        local_size = file_size / size;
        local_counts = (int *)calloc(MAX + 1, sizeof(int));
    }

    MPI_Bcast(&local_size, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    local_data = (int *)malloc(local_size * sizeof(int));
    MPI_Scatter(buffer, local_size, MPI_INT, local_data, local_size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for (int i = 0; i < local_size; i++) {
        count[local_data[i]]++;
    }

    local_counts = (int *)malloc((MAX + 1) * size * sizeof(int));
    MPI_Gather(count, MAX + 1, MPI_INT, local_counts, MAX + 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0) {
        int total[MAX + 1] = {0};
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= MAX; j++) {
                total[j] += local_counts[i * (MAX + 1) + j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < MAX; i++) {
            total[i] += total[i - 1];
        }

        MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_SELF, file_name, MPI_MODE_WRONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &file);
        offset = 0;
        MPI_File_write_at(file, offset, total, MAX + 1, MPI_INT, &status);
        offset += (MAX + 1) * sizeof(int);
        MPI_File_write_at_all(file, offset, buffer, file_size / sizeof(int), MPI_INT, &status);
        MPI_File_close(&file);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

The problem is that this gives a memory ranges overlap error, as shown when I run this (note that it properly shows the statement for inserting a file name):
Assertion failed in file src/mpi/misc/utils.c at line 55: FALSE
memcpy argument memory ranges overlap, dst_=0x555f7f95b820 src_=0x555f7f9569f0 len_=80000

internal ABORT - process 0

Can you find a a way to fix this? Note that I am running this code on a Google Cloud virtual machine using Ubuntu.

What happens if if (rank == 0) is false? How will buffer be initialized?

And have you tried to catch the crash in a debugger to find out where in your code it happens? And why do you initialize local_counts twice? Which one is valid? Oh, and in C you shouldn't really cast the result of malloc (etc.).

It would be helpful to know which function is asserting. If it is calling abort, it should be creating a core file. Make sure you've set "ulimit -c unlimited" to allow the core file. From there you can use gdb (or some other debugger) to get a stack traceback. Alternatively, run the program directly from gdb.

Are you sure an MPI_Offset is an int? Are you sure that for example, MPI_Bcast(&local_size, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); is a valid call?

count[local_data[i]] could be suspicious. are you sure 0 <= local_data[i] <= MAX ?


memcpy argument memory ranges overlap, dst_=0x555f7f95b820 src_=0x555f7f9569f0 len_=80000

the difference between the two pointers is 20016 bytes, while you have ordered a copy of 80000 bytes (about four times larger), so they overlap, effectively.  You need to check the calls to memcpy() (or the buffer copying routines) to isolate where you probably have an uninitialized/mangled size of the buffer array... or the most probably reason can be that you have not converted a sizeof (which is the size of an object in bytes) to the number of array elements (which for integers is normally one quarter of the size ;-) ) result into a number of elements properly and you are using a huge array size.
Also, don't trust that what you have read and the file size to be the same value, more if you have not been able to read it completely.
I cannot give more help because the MPI library is new to me, I have never used it.
